# Как остановить input() в Python?

Tags: python, input

В главном меню находится `input()` для ввода команды, который ожидает ввода всё время.
В какой-то момент может понадобиться принять сигнал из постороннего потока и вывести на экран. Но так как работает `input`, пока он не получит ввод, ничего не выведется.

Я находил вариант решения:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    # Code
```

Это бы помогло, но в этот `input` нельзя ввести текст (как `input('>>> ')`).

Есть ли возможность сделать подобное?

Answer (score 3):

Решение нужно искать не в том, как остановить ввод с клавиатуры, а в многопоточности. Задачи ожидания сигнала и ввода с клавиатуры нужно реализовать в разных потоках.

Если же они как-то связаны, то нужно не ждать ввода, а в цикле проверять наличие символов во входном буфере.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня они, как раз таки, и находятся в отдельных потоках.
Но когда в любой части кода встречается `input`, то любой остальной код приостанавливается до ввода. Можно поподробнее про "проверять наличие символов во входном буфере"?

Comment: Окей, проблема была в работе IDLE, в которой я проверяю код резких от ошибок. В консоли всё нормально.